# Using segmented control to switch tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to change my table view cell when the segmented control is changed here is what I have now

```
internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var returnValue = 0

    switch(segmentedC.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        returnValue = rest.count
        break
    case 1:
        returnValue = fullMenu.count
        break
    default:
        break

    }

    return returnValue
}
```

I have this for my `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("food") as! restTableViewCell
    var cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("fullM") as! fullmenuTableViewCell
    switch(segmentedC.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        let res: Rest!
        res = rest[indexPath.row]

        var img: UIImage?

        if let urls = foo.imageString{
            img = foodViewController.imageCache.objectForKey(urls) as? UIImage

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.setupViews(res)

        }

        break
    case 1:
            cell2.textLabel?.text = fullMenu[indexPath.row]
        break

    default:
        break

    }
    return cell
}
```

Also I have an `IBAction` for the segmented control

```
@IBAction func seg(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch(segmentedC.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        tableView.reloadData()
        break

    case 1:
        tableView.reloadData()
        break
    default:
        break

    }

}
```

But when I change the segment only one cell from the `index 0` show up in the `index 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath you are always returning cell you are never returning cell2. Try  returning cell2 in your second case.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("food") as! restTableViewCell
var cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("fullM") as! fullmenuTableViewCell
switch(segmentedC.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
case 0:
    let res: Rest!
    res = rest[indexPath.row]

    var img: UIImage?

    if let urls = foo.imageString{
        img = foodViewController.imageCache.objectForKey(urls) as? UIImage

    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        cell.setupViews(res)

    }

    break
case 1:
        cell2.textLabel?.text = fullMenu[indexPath.row]
        return cell2
    break

default:
    break

}
return cell
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked thank you!. But is this the best way to use segmented control with tableviews?

Comment: Depends on your use case dude i don't know your use case so i can't be sure if this approach is best or not but i can suggest some improvements like you don't need cases in your IBAction func seg(sender: AnyObject) just calling reload once will do, and for an added bonus the break behaviour is by default for switch in swift so if you remove all the break it will work exactly the same.

Comment: Am experiencing slow loading when cell is tapped any idea why?

Comment: Can you share your didSelectRowAtIndexPath code? Might be some issue there.

Comment: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        var foo:Food!
        foo = food[indexPath.row]
        var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Vc", sender: foo)

    }`

Comment: This is the didSelectRow that has problem

Comment: Try using tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false) instead of selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() and see if this helps.